# merging two list of dictionary with same Keys' value added and if key not found still add with value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

## Invoice

`[{'A': 5, 'B': 10, 'C': 15}, {'A': 5, 'B': 25, 'C': 17, 'D': 30, }]`

## Bank

`[{'A': 5, 'G': 10, 'Q': 15}, {'A': 5, 'B': 25, 'M': 17, 'T': 30, }]`

**After merge**

## Answer

`[{'A':10,'B':10,'C':15,'G':10,'Q':15},{'A':10,'B':50,'C':17,'D':30,'M':17,'T':30}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to merge the counts between both paired dictionaries created from [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from collections import Counter

l1 = [{'A': 5, 'B': 10, 'C': 15}, {'A': 5, 'B': 25, 'C': 17, 'D': 30, }]

l2 = [{'A': 5, 'G': 10, 'Q': 15}, {'A': 5, 'B': 25, 'M': 17, 'T': 30, }]

result = [Counter(x) + Counter(y) for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[Counter({'C': 15, 'Q': 15, 'A': 10, 'B': 10, 'G': 10}), Counter({'B': 50, 'D': 30, 'T': 30, 'C': 17, 'M': 17, 'A': 10})]
```

<sup>`Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, so you can treat it like a normal dictionary. You can cast it to `dict` if you want your result to look like `[{'A': 10, 'B': 10, 'C': 15, 'G': 10, 'Q': 15}, {'A': 10, 'B': 50, 'C': 17, 'D': 30, 'M': 17, 'T': 30}]`.</sup>

Why the above works from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> Several mathematical operations are provided for combining Counter objects to produce multisets (counters that have counts greater than zero). Addition and subtraction combine counters by adding or subtracting the counts of corresponding elements. Intersection and union return the minimum and maximum of corresponding counts. Each operation can accept inputs with signed counts, but the output will exclude results with counts of zero or less.